# Flickering - Change CSS Background Position on Window Scroll

Tags: javascript, css, parallax

I'm going to rephrase my question due to lack of views.  Does anyone know why modifying background-position on window scroll for Chrome and IE causes flickering sometimes?

Basically something like this will always cause flickering in Chrome and IE:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){$(divwithbg).css('background-position','center '+positiveinteger+px')});
```

Something like this never seems to flicker in any major browser:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){$(divwithbg).css('background-position','center '+negativeinteger+px')});
```

If you want to see this problem, try my sample code below, along with attached image.  If you set data-parallaxdirection="0", that will be jitter free.  If you set data-parallaxdirection="1", that will have jittering.  I've attached the image I was using to this post.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
        <style type="text/css">
        .parallax-container {width:100%; position:relative; display:block; overflow:hidden; background-color:black; background-position:center center; background-repeat:no-repeat;}

        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>


        <script type="text/javascript">
var CONTAINER = window;
var AVAILHEIGHT;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(ParallaxScrollEvent);
    AVAILHEIGHT = $(window).height();
    $('.parallax-container').height(AVAILHEIGHT/1.1);
});

function ParallaxScroll(obj)
{
    var containerTop = $(obj).position().top;
    var containerHeight = $(obj).height();
    var parallaxspace = parseInt($(obj).attr('data-parallaxspace'));
    var goforward = parseInt($(obj).attr('data-parallaxdirection'));
    var scrollTop =  $(window).scrollTop() + AVAILHEIGHT;

//  var links = $('.location-links'); //on contact page


    if( scrollTop > containerTop)
    {
            var pos = 0;
            if(goforward)
            {
                            // why does this cause flickering?
                var scrolled = $(window).scrollTop() - containerTop;
                pos = 1.2*scrolled;

            }
            else
            {
                            // why is this flicker free?
                pos = -1*(scrollTop-containerTop)*parallaxspace/(2*containerHeight);
            }
            $(obj).css('background-position', 'center '+pos+'px');
    }
}

function ParallaxScrollEvent()
{
    var parallaxcontainer = $('.parallax-container');
    for(var c=0; c< parallaxcontainer.length; c++)
        ParallaxScroll(parallaxcontainer[c]);
}

        </script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="parallax-container" style="background-image:url(images/location/2.jpg);" data-parallaxdirection="1" data-parallaxspace="800">
            </div>
            <div class="parallax-container" style="background-image:url(images/location/2.jpg);" data-parallaxdirection="1" data-parallaxspace="800">
            </div>
            <div class="parallax-container" style="background-image:url(images/location/2.jpg);" data-parallaxdirection="1" data-parallaxspace="800">
            </div>

</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed the problem.

I added a `background-attachment:fixed` to my `.parallax-container` .